# JS not executing

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have this code:

```
if ($has_freechat1 && $has_freechat2)
{
    if (($has_freechat1['confirmed'] == 1) && ($has_freechat2['confirmed'] == 1))
    { 
        $was_clicked = 0;
?>
<a href="freechatcontacts.php?id=<?php echo $id_to.$was_clicked; ?>" class="charcoal_link" style="line-height: 20px;" name="message" id="message" onClick="return send('<?php echo $was_clicked;?> return false;')">
<?php echo $uniqueCode1?><span class="pink_text"><?php echo $uniqueCode2?></span><?php echo $uniqueCode3?>
</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;       
<?php                         
        if ($was_clicked == 1)
        {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="password" type="textarea" rows="10" cols="20" value="<?php echo $aCleanPost['message']['value']?>" /></td>
  </tr>        
  <tr>
    <td><br /><input name="cmdSubmit" type="submit" value="Send" /><br/>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <?php         
        }
 }
```

the above displays a uniquecode link, when i click on it i want an html textarea to display so user can type in a short message..the onlcick send() is a JS function but it does not execute it so i can set $was_clicked to 1

how can i get round this problem?
please help
thank you

**Edit**
`sendMessage` function from comments:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function send(val)
{
   val = 1; //was clicked 
   return val;
}
</script>
```

Comment: which is the browser that you are using to browser.

Comment: Can you post sendMessage function definition?

Comment: i use chromium now and here is the php sendMessage:

    function sendMessage()
    {
    ?>
       <tr>
         <td><input name="password" type="textarea" rows="10" cols="20" value="<?php echo $aCleanPost['message']['value']?>" /></td>
       </tr>     
       <tr>
         <td><br /><input name="cmdSubmit" type="submit" value="Send" /><br/>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
    <?php
    }

thank you

Comment: Stupid question, does mobi == mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onclick handler must call a javascript function, not a php function.

Comment: Do you have a javascript sendMessage function?  Please show us that one :)

Comment: mobi = mobile :) and here is my JAVASCRIPT function: 
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function sendMessage(val)
    {
       //var val = document.getElementById('message').value; 
       document.write(val);
       return val;
    }
    </script>

it is not doing the document.write

Answer (score 0):

Your code syntax seems wrong.

```
onClick="return send('<?php echo $was_clicked;?> return false;')">
```

Try

```
onClick="javascript:send('<?php echo $was_clicked;?>'); return false;">
```